# How to create relative path URLs in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need to use relative paths for my site (Lets just say for reasons I don't want to get into it has to be relative).

Currently I'm using the following in my site:

```
# url to controller
{{  Form::open(array('url' => 'users/signin') }}

# url to controller
 <li><a href="{{action('UsersController@getLogout')}}" class="navbar-brand "> <span class=""></span> Logout </a></li>

# url to style
{{ HTML::style('css/main.css')}}
```

I've tried others too but all of them constructs absolute URLs such as:

```
http://localhost:8888/mysite/users/logout
```

In vanilla PHP i could place relative paths like this:

```
<li><a href="../search/">Search</a></li>
```

I abandoned `HTML::style()` and used relative URLs on my css,js etc. like this which works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
```

However how can do this for links to controller methods?

Comment: Regarding saying you use relative URLs on your CSS and Javascript: /css/main.css *is* an absolute URI. Absolute URIs begin with a forward slash. They result in the same page being requested no matter what URI hierarchy you may be on. I assume you want to get rid of the host; i.e., the bit before the URI?

Comment: @MilosIvanovic: You're right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this isn't possible out-of-the-box with Laravel 4. I did find [someone's modification of the URL class in Laravel](https://gist.github.com/damienlabat/3715529) which allows this, but it does mean you are using third-party code for otherwise integrated functionality.

Comment: Thanks. Have you used this? Do you create the `bundles` dir and place the files in them?